# How concatenate encodeWithSignature with another data type to external call?

Tags: solidity, abi

There are a `abi.encodeWithSignature("foo((bytes))", info)`, but in addition to calling the function in another contract I want to send more data as an `address` to retrieve with msg.data, for example. It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure of what your are looking for but if you want to send more parameters than required in the signature you can do something like that

```
function send(bytes memory info, address moreInfo) public {
    (bool success,) = address(this).call(abi.encodePacked(abi.encodeWithSignature("foo((bytes))", info), moreInfo));
}
    
function foo(bytes memory info) public {
    address moreInfo = address(0);
    if (msg.data.length >= 24) { // you should check msg.sender too
        assembly {
            moreInfo := shr(96,calldataload(sub(calldatasize(),20)))
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify multiple types in the [function signature](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/abi-spec.html#function-selector). For example:

```
abi.encodeWithSignature("foo(uint256,address)", 12345, address(0x0));
```

This will result in:

```
0xa68b44f800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030390000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```